# Помогите составить регулярное выражение исключающее фигурные скобки из паттерна

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

есть регулярное выражение для парсинга имени переменной и её формата.

```
var pattern= @"\{(.*?)(:.+?)?\}"
var str="0x57{Nbyte:X2}hhh"

 var matches = Regex.Matches(str, pattern)

 match.Groups[0].Value - все выражение {Nbyte:X2}
 match.Groups[1].Value - имя переменной Nbyte
 match.Groups[2].Value - формат :X2
```

Если инженеры неверно задавали строку

```
 var str = "0x57{Nbyte:X2 fff {CRCXor[0x02-0x03]:X2}";
 {Nbyte:X2 - забыли закр. скобку
```

то программа говорила об ошибке (и это было хорошо))), теперь появилось куча новых протоколов и такая ситуация может быть валидной.
 Т.е. нужно просто игнорировать `{Nbyte:X2` при парсинге, а выделить только `{CRCXor[0x02-0x03]:X2} строку`.

```
Резульат парсинга:
     match.Groups[0].Value - все выражение {Nbyte:X2 fff {CRCXor[0x02-0x03]:X2}
     match.Groups[1].Value - имя переменной Nbyte
     match.Groups[2].Value - формат :X2 fff {CRCXor[0x02-0x03]:X2
```

Я думаю надо задать правило - внутри выделенной строки не должноб быть скобок, {}.
Помогите пожалуйста добавить исключающее правило на {,}

Comment: `\{([^\{\}:]+)(:[^\}\{]+)?\}` Full match `{CRCXor[0x02-0x03]:X2}` Group 1 `CRCXor[0x02-0x03]` Group 2 `:X2`

Comment: Это блок исключений [^\}\{] я так понял?

Comment: Спасибо работает!

Comment: Да, выбираем все символы после открывающейся фигурной скобки, до первого  двоеточия открывающихся и закрывающихся фигурных скобок, потом от двоеточия выбираем так же все символы если они есть за исключением открывающихся или закрывающихся фигурных скобок, стоит учесть, что если фигурные скобки расставлены корректно, данный запрос все равно возьмет внутренние фигурные скобки.

Comment: Понял, например {kkk} - тоже подходит под шаблон, хотя : там не указанно. Впринципе нормально.

Comment: Если обе группы обязательны то следует убрать последний вопросительный знак, тогда только при совпадении двух групп будет выбор, делал на подобии с вашим шаблоном, у вас там так же спадения на вторую группу 0 или 1, т.е. в шаблоне она необязательно указана, без вопросительного знака `{KKK}` не будет попадать в выборку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\{([^:{]+):([^{}]+)\}
```

https://regex101.com/r/SK6Eax/2

Это более корректный вариант регулярки, написанной **PotroNik** в комментарии к вопросу.
Исправлено излишнее экранирование внутри символьных классов.
И символ `:` в выражении размещен вне групп (если это всего лишь разделитель, то по-моему, нет смысла его захватывать).

Нюансы: здесь содержимое обеих групп *не* опционально - то есть, будет совпадение только когда есть хотя бы один символ и до, и после двоеточия... и, пробельные символы не "фильтруются" выражением.

Comment: В первой группе `[^:{]` е̶д̶и̶н̶о̶р̶о̶г̶ с̶ у̶с̶а̶м̶и̶ матчит любые символы кроме `{` и `:`, далее буквально символ `:` (не захватываем его), и затем вторая группа с `[^{}]` матчит любые символы кроме фигурных скобок.

Comment: А чего плохого в двоеточии?

Comment: @Qwertiy, судя по комментарию автора _«например {kkk} - тоже подходит под шаблон, хотя : там не указанно»_, двоеточие должно быть критерием, но из текста вопроса следует что в захвате оно не нужно, т.к. является разделителем (хотя возможно, что я понял задачу неправильно).

Comment: Спасибо за участие!

Comment: : должно захватываться в формат. Уже разобрался что к чему)

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно как-то так:

```
var pattern = @"\{([^{}]*?)(:[^{}]+?)?\}";
```

Comment: Ну вот, такое уже есть... А, нет, в одном символе отличается.