# Добавить еще одну группу соответсвия в регулярное выражение

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте данный вопрос является продолжением вопроса

[Помогите составить регулярное выражение исключающее фигурные скобки из паттерна](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1062244/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Вкратце, для выделения перменной и ее формата из строки использую паттерн

```
Pattern = "\{([^:{]+)(:[^{}]+)?\}"
```

Патерн используемый сейчас выделяет 2 группы, но понадобилось ввести еще одну НЕ ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНУЮ группу.

```
var str ="0x57{Nbyte(а-С):X2}hhh"
Groups[0] = {Nbyte(а-С):X2}
Groups[1] = Nbyte
Groups[2] = (а-С)    - новая группа
Groups[3] = :X2

1 группа - выделяет имя переменной (исключая 2 симола :{) -  ([^:{]+)
2 группа - должна быделить НЕ ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНЫЕ опции заключенные в () или []. внутри опций может быть симол : но не может быть символов {}
3 группа - выделяет формат (вместе с :) исключая симолы {} - (:[^{}]+)
```

Примеры:

```
var str ="0x57{Nbyte:X2}hhh"
Groups[0] = {Nbyte:X2}
Groups[1] = Nbyte
Groups[2] = 
Groups[3] = :X2

var str ="0x57{Nbyte}hhh"
Groups[0] = {Nbyte}
Groups[1] = Nbyte
Groups[2] = 
Groups[3] =

var str ="0x57{Nbyte[:-+]:X2}hhh"
Groups[0] = {Nbyte[:-+]:X2}
Groups[1] = Nbyte
Groups[2] = [:-+]
Groups[3] =:X2

var str ="0x57{Nbyte[:-+]}hhh"
Groups[0] = {Nbyte[:-+]}
Groups[1] = Nbyte
Groups[2] = [:-+]
Groups[3] =

var str ="0x57{Nbyte[{hghfghgtf]:X2}hhh" 
- опции не валидны, т.к. внутри [] содержится симол {
```

P.S. Напишите пожалуста подробные кооментарии на регулярку в ответе.

Comment: Пока вы не определитесь с **требованиями** к строке, вы ещё долго будете задавать вопросы. Что вы хотите найти? Подстроку типа: 1) начинается с `{`, 2) затем следует идентификатор (как название переменной, только цифры, буквы, _), 3) затем всё в скобках (????), кроме `{` и `}`, 4) `:`, 5) дальше всё, кроме `{` и `}` и 6) `}`. Так?

Comment: `\{(\w+)(\([^()]*\)|\[[^][]*])?(:[^{}]+)?}`??? [Демо](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%7b%28%5cw%2b%29%28%5c%28%5b%5e%28%29%5d*%5c%29%7c%5c%5b%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d*%5d%29%3f%28%3a%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d%2b%29%3f%7d&i=0x57%7bNbyte%3aX2%7dhhh%0d%0a0x57%7bNbyte%28%d0%b0-%d0%a1%29%3aX2%7dhhh%0d%0a0x57%7bNbyte%7dhhh%0d%0a0x57%7bNbyte%5b%3a-%2b%5d%3aX2%7dhhh%0d%0a0x57%7bNbyte%5b%3a-%2b%5d%7dhhh%0d%0a0x57%7bNbyte%5b%7bhghfghgtf%5d%3aX2%7dhhh)

Comment: Только скобки в блоке опций могут быть не только () но и могут быть []

Comment: И в блоке опций не может быть {}

Comment: Ок, `\{(\w+)(\([^(){}]*\)|\[[^][{}]*])?(:[^{}]+)?}`? https://regex101.com/r/SK6Eax/5

Comment: Требования к строке очень долго были одни, теперь поменялись. В чем проблема что я задал еще 1 вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос неясен, проблема только в этом.

Comment: Работает! спасибо большое. А не могли бы вы раписать подробнее регуляркув полноценном ответе к моему вопросу?

Comment: Эту - `\{(\w+)(\([^(){}]*\)|\[[^][{}]*])?(:[^{}]+)?}` ? Но она не находит `0x57{Nbyte[{hghfghgtf]:X2}hhh`. Эту - `\{(\w+)(\([^()]*\)|\[[^][]*])?(:[^{}]+)?}`?

Comment: \{(\w+)(\([^(){}]*\)|\[[^][{}]*])?(:[^{}]+)?} - эта подходит, верно что в блоке опций могут быть все симолы кроме {}

Comment: Т.е. ваш последний пример неверен? В `var str ="0x57{Nbyte[{hghfghgtf]:X2}hhh"`  вообще не должно быть совпадений?

Comment: Получается неверн, сейчас исправлю.

Comment: Да, получается если в опциях есть скобки {}, то совпадений быть не должно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```
\{(\w+)(\([^(){}]*\)|\[[^][{}]*])?(:[^{}]+)?}
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%7b%28%5cw%2b%29%28%5c%28%5b%5e%28%29%7b%7d%5d*%5c%29%7c%5c%5b%5b%5e%5d%5b%7b%7d%5d*%5d%29%3f%28%3a%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d%2b%29%3f%7d&i=0x57%7bNbyte%3aX2%7dhhh%0d%0a0x57%7bNbyte%28%d0%b0-%d0%a1%29%3aX2%7dhhh%0d%0a0x57%7bNbyte%7dhhh%0d%0a0x57%7bNbyte%5b%3a-%2b%5d%3aX2%7dhhh%0d%0a0x57%7bNbyte%5b%3a-%2b%5d%7dhhh%0d%0a0x57%7bNbyte%5b%7bhghfghgtf%5d%3aX2%7dhhh).

**Подробности**

- `\{` - открывающая скобка
- `(\w+)` - Группа №1: 1+ букв, цифр, _
- `(\([^(){}]*\)|\[[^][{}]*])?` - опциональная группа, находит

  - `\([^(){}]*\)` - `(`, 0+ символов, отличных от `(`, `)`, `{` и `}`, `)`
  - `|` -
  - `\[[^][{}]*]` - `[`, 0+ символов, отличных от `[`, `]`, `{` и `}`, `]`
- `(:[^{}]+)?` - опциональная группа, находит `:`, 1+ символов, отличных от `{` и `}`
- `}` - закрывающая скобка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо огромоное, буду разбираться.